# How to find and remove the invisible characters in text file using emacs

Tags: emacs, line-breaks, carriage-return, line-endings, eol

I have a `.txt` file named COPYING which is edited on windows.
It contains Windows-style line breaks :

```
$ file COPYING 
COPYING: ASCII English text, with CRLF line terminators
```

I tried to convert it to Unix style using `dos2unix`. Below is the output :

```
$ dos2unix COPYING 
dos2unix: Skipping binary file COPYING
```

I was surprised to find that the `dos2unix` program reports it as a binary file. Then using some other editor (not Emacs) I found that the file contains a control character. I am interested in finding all the invisible characters in the file using Emacs.

By googling, I have found the following solution which uses `tr` :

```
tr -cd '\11\12\40-\176' < file_name
```

How can I do the same in an Emacs way? I tried the Hexl mode. The Hexl mode shows text and their corresponding ASCII values in a single buffer which is great. How do I find the characters which have ASCII values other than 11-12, 40-176 (i.e tab, space, and visible characters)? I tried to create a regular expression for that search, but it is quite complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs won't hide any character by default. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd>, or <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> if the former is too hard on your fingers, or `M-x replace-regexp RET` if you prefer. Then, for the regular expression, enter

```
[^@-^H^K-^_^?]
```

However, where I wrote `^H`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, to enter a “control-H” character literally, and similarly for the others. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for `^@`, and usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> for `^?`. Replace all occurrences of this regular expression by the empty string.

Since you have the file open in Emacs, you can change its line endings while you're at it. Press `C-x RET f` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>) and enter `us-ascii-unix` as the new desired encoding for the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to understand what the regular expression does. I typed the command "describe-character-set" then selected the "ascii" to see the character set. Could you please explain why did you miss the C-j and where the C-? is documented.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit `C-i` is tab, `C-j` is newline.

Comment: This link http://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/tcl-course/emacs-tutorial.html says C-m is for RET key. I am not able to find the doc where C-? is documented. Could you please point it out.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit I can't find this documented explicitly in the manual. There's brief mention of `C-?` in [If <DEL> Fails to Delete](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html#DEL-Does-Not-Delete), and character 127 is often called the DEL character and produced by the Backspace or Delete key.

Answer (score 20):

To see invisible characters, you can try `whitespace-mode`.  Spaces and tabs will be displayed with a symbol in a different face.  If the coding system is automatically being detected as dos (showing `(DOS)` on the status bar), carriage returns at the end of a line will be hidden as well.  Run `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` to switch it to Unix or binary (e.g. <kbd>C-x RET r unix</kbd>) and they'll always show up as `^M`.  The binary coding system will display any non-ASCII characters as control characters as well.

Comment: All the characters does not show up as ^M. I have a very large file i can see some of the characters as ^L. I dont know how many such characters are out there in the file. I want to search for those characters.

Comment: There are many, many invisible characters that are not shown by `whitespace-mode`. Amongst them: zero-width space, zero-width non-joiner, zero-width joiner, byte-order mark... See how [fingerprinting](https://medium.com/@aidobreen/hidden-text-fingerprints-and-how-to-avoid-them-d0103edd2ce4) uses them, and the dangers of neglecting them.
You might want to reflect that into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system`. From the documentation:

> `(set-buffer-file-coding-system CODING-SYSTEM &optional FORCE NOMODIFY)`
>
> Set the file coding-system of the current buffer to CODING-SYSTEM.
>   This means that when you save the buffer, it will be converted
>   according to CODING-SYSTEM.  For a list of possible values of
>   CODING-SYSTEM, use M-x list-coding-systems.

So, going from DOS to UNIX, `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system unix`.